# Extend ember class on condition

Tags: javascript, class, ember.js, extends, discourse

Is it possible to extend Ember class on condition? Something like this:

```
A.reopen({
  if (condition) {
    init: function() {
      this.super();
      // some functionality
    }.on('didInsertElement');
  }
})
```

Currently I have such pattern:

```
A.reopen({
  init: function() {
    this.super();
    if (condition) {
      // some stuff
    }
  }.on('didInsertElement'),

  cleanup: function() {
    if (condition) {
      // some stuff
    }
  }.on('willDestroyElement')
})
```

I guessed if I can extend A class on condition I can simplify my pattern like this:

```
A.reopen({
  if (condition) {
    init: function() {
      this.super();
      // some functionality
    }.on('didInsertElement'),

    clear_up: function() {
      // some stuff
    }.on('willDestroyElement')
  }
})
```

All class extensions made in the plugin for [discourse](http://www.discourse.org/)

Comment: Why not switch first and second line? What class you want to reopen and whats your use case?

Comment: @Keo I've updated the question to clarify my case

Comment: Doesn't Keo's answer help you?  
`if (condition) { 
A.reopen({ `

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want what in Java would be called an abstract class.

```
Ember.Component.extend({ // abstract class

  doSomeInit: Ember.K,

  doSomeCleaning: Ember.K,

  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.super(..arguments);
    this.doSomeInit();
  },

  willDestroyElement: function() {
    this.doSomeCleaning();
  }
})

// class A
Ember.Component.extend(MyIncompleteClass, {

  doSomeInit: function() { /* etc */ },

  doSomeCleaning: function() { /* etc */ }

});

// class B
Ember.Component.extend(MyIncompleteClass, {

  doSomeInit: function() { /* etc */ },

  doSomeCleaning: function() { /* etc */ }

});
```

Sidenote: Is best to override the lifecycle hooks than to use Ember.on, to guarantee order of execution; that is in the case of multiple Ember.on for the same event.

Comment: I'm extending ember classes from plugin, I can't create my own classes even abstract

Comment: mind updating your question with that bit? how are you extending from the plugin? (ember cli addon, I assume)